# Flask server to notify webclient when changes occur

Tags: python, events, flask

I am building a server using `Flask` that will be called by a `web client`.

When a certain change occurs on the `db` my `Flask` app interacts with, I need the `web client` to be alerted so it can display the update.

Would someone be able to give me some direction as to what I should be looking into with regards to both the `Flask` and `web client` sides?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminology you are using is a little confusing. I'm going to assume the web client is someone visiting your Flask app over the internet.

Basically, if you want the ability for the server to push updates to the client you need to use websockets

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: Thanks @vicg. Yes, you are correct - that's what I meant. I came across this for Flask (http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent).. will continue to try get a better understanding of all this.